# On and off switch detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this little code that I found, I was wondering how could you detect if the users input is off, or on? Using Jquery or JS,

Here is a snip bit of code, and a link to my fiddle.

```
#check {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 50px;
display: inline-block;
background: #51bd9f;
width: 70px;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5r4byad/)**

Comment: That's called "CSS" and has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The jquery to find out if its on or off is:

```
$('#check').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')==true){
        //off
    }else{
        //on
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a listener for 'click' event. And use .prop('checked') to determine if on/off.

```
$( '#check' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    var status = $( this ).prop( 'checked' ) ? 'off' : 'on';
    alert( status );
});
```

Updated JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/richardgirges/k5r4byad/4/

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript's way to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("Unchecked");
    }
}
</script>
```

Modify your `input` tag as..

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()"></input>
```

also a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/345yb2b5/). You may modify it if required.